# Adding inline links in LLM response

Tags: large-language-model, gpt-4

## Background

Bing Copilot's response is partially clickable. That means, some sentences are links. I'd like to have this feature in my LLM.

In [this discussion](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/generative-ai/discussions/248), it is recommended to lookup the source document and then:

> feed that link as part of the prompt to the LLM and do some prompt engineering to also return the documentation link alongside the response.

Based on my understanding, the response can then be converted to HTML with `<a href="...">` tags as a post-processing step.

## Question

Given that the source documents are provided in the prompt, as recommended, what should the prompt include in order to get a response that can be converted into clickable sentences as a post-process step?

Comment: Check out langchain and this link: https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/cookbook/retrieval#with-memory-and-returning-source-documents

Comment: Depending on what your source document(s) is you first have to find a way to reference to a section of it. This may be as specific or generic as you define. As you did not include what kind of documents you are referring to I can only give you examples: if your documents are websites you could use the url as reference. So before each websites content insert its url as identifier. Then in your prompt tell the LLM that it should use the content and provide references etc. Give an example of how you would like the references to be formatted e.g. like in markdown `[link name](link)`.

Comment: ChatGPT-4 has a similar feature and gives the following instruction on how to format references: 
"... [instruction on how to browse the internet] ...
3. Write a response to the user based on these results. In your response, cite sources using the citation format below.
... [some other unrelated instructions] ...
For citing quotes from the 'browser' tool: please render in this format: `【{message idx}†{link text}】`
For long citations: please render in this format: `[link text](message idx)`.
Otherwise do not render links."